# How do you conditionally use hooks in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have two hooks. One is called `useLocalStorage` and the other is called `useQuery`.
Based on an input prop, I want to conditionally use one of them.

Is it OK if I simply write `const [value, setValue] = localStorage ? useLocalStorage() : useQuery()` ?

Comment: No, I wouldn't do that.   A simple solution is conditionally render different components instead, these components could then use the relevant use hook.

Answer (score 6):

You should never call hooks conditionally. This is because the same hooks need to be called in the same order everytime the component is rendered. See the [Rules of Hooks](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level).

Depending on your use case, you could consider rendering the hooks every-time but adding a condition to their output.

```js
const localStorageOutput = useLocalStorage();
const queryOutput = useQuery();
const [value, setValue] = localStorage ? localStorageOutput : queryOutput;
```

This could have unintended side-effects, especially if your prop value of `localStorage` changes.